# WooCommerce modify cart totals programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to change the cart totals with code but I don't know how. I have managed to change the price for each item in the cart using the filter `woocommerce_cart_item_price`. Is there such a filter for the cart totals(see arrow in picture)?
[image]

This is the code for each individual item:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'func_change_product_price_cart', 10, 3 );
function func_change_product_price_cart($price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key){
if ( isset($cart_item['tau_lengde']) ) {
if ( WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {

    $product_price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $cart_item['data'] );
} else {
    $product_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $cart_item['data'] );
}
    $price = wc_price( (($product_price * $cart_item['tau_lengde']) + $cart_item['price_one_end'] + $cart_item['price_other_end']));

return $price;
}
```

}

Comment: Add some code. The code of your cart etc...

Comment: I added code in the question

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_total', 'wc_modify_cart_price' ); 

function wc_modify_cart_price( $price ) {

    $addition = 10;
    return  $price+addition;
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55168648/1117368)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'modify_calculated_total', 20, 2 );

function modify_calculated_total( $total, $cart ) {

    return $total + 10;

}
```

Item total = A fixed amount * Quantity

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'modify_cart_price', 20, 1);

function modify_cart_price( $cart_obj ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ))
        return;

    foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( 1000);
    }
 }
```

Item total = Item price * Quantity ( Default )

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'modify_cart_price', 20, 1);

function modify_cart_price( $cart_obj ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ))
        return;

    foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $cart_item['data']->get_price());
    }
 }
```

Product subtotal in cart

```
function filter_woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal( $product_subtotal, $product, $quantity, $instance ) { 

    $product_subtotal = $product->get_price()*$quantity;
    return $product_subtotal; 
}; 


add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: When I tried this code the total for each item is still the variation price(see arrows in picture), but the totals on the bottom of the page is now 0.

Comment: @Paudun Try the new snippet  in answer- That is what you are looking for?

Comment: The new snippet worked on the total price showing on the bottom of the page, but not for the total next to the arrows.

Comment: @Paudun Next to the arrow means? Item total price? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I updated the picture in the question. I'm trying to modify the price the arrow is pointing at. Right now it just displays the item variation price which is 50. Your code changed the price on the bottom where it says 10269.

Comment: @Paudun Check the last snippet

Comment: The last snippet also added 1000 several times to the item price to the left of the arrow in the picture :p

Comment: @Paudun qunatity * a fixed amount thats what you want right?

Comment: I want to get the value to the left of the arrow(1250) and multiply it with the quantity selected, and then put it where the arrow is.

Comment: @Paudun Updated your final snippet :)

Comment: The final snippet still modifies the value to the left of the arrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190078/discussion-between-mujuonly-and-paudun).

Comment: Is there any way to use cart_item[''] within function filter_woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal( $product_subtotal, $product, $quantity, $instance )?

Comment: @Paudun yes. $instance in that hook is $cart

Comment: so i can just type $a_variable = $cart_item['length']; ?

Comment: foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $cart_item['data']->get_length();
    }

Comment: what does the foreach do?

Comment: I think the woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal runs on every item in the cart individually